# настройка gunicorn + nginx

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

есть такой момент, я настроил gunicorn + nginx + django на своём сервере, подрубил домен. При переходе по домену я получаю 404 ошибку и пути куда можно перейти, /admin, /api и тд.

Мне нужно что бы при переходе на домен меня сразу кидало в админку.

До этого я настраивал так что бы запускать gunicorn вручную через --daemon. 
И в этом случае я мог прописать так:

```
location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/;
    }
location /admin/ {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/;
    }
location /api/ {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/;
    }
```

Но сейчас настройка такая:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/backend;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/user/backend;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

И я не могу прописать так же.

Comment: Просто редирект с нужными параметрами да и всё `location = / { return 302 /admin/; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил эту проблему так:

```bsh
upstream django {
    server unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    server 127.0.0.1:8000
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.ru www.sub.domain.ru;
    location /favicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root path_to_project; #  example = root /home/backend;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root path_to_project; #  example = root /home/backend;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        uwsgi_pass django;
        proxy_pass http://django/admin/; 
    }
    location /admin/ {
        include proxy_params;
        uwsgi_pass django;
        proxy_pass http://django/admin/; 
    }
    location /api/ {
        include proxy_params;
        uwsgi_pass django;
        proxy_pass http://django/api/; 
    }
}
```